# Mount two davfs2 WEBDAV partition with two different configuration

Tags: debian, webdav, davfs2

I have two WEBDAV different partition,
One in /WEBDAV and another in /WEBDAV_TEST.
I'm using davfs2.
There is same way to have two different davfs2 configuration for this two partition?
I want the first one without cache and the second one with cache.
The user is the same : root.
any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have different configurations. When used as root, only the system config file is used but it still allows configuration by mount point.

From the [help](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/davfs2.conf.5.html):

```
   kernel_fs fuse
   proxy     foo.bar:8080
   use_displayname 0
   [/media/dav]
   use_displayname 1
   [/home/otto/mywebspace]
   use_locks 0
```

However, I'm not sure you can entirely disable the cache. I think that it always caches open files no matter what you set it to.